# Usar uma variável em uma activity declarada em outra activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Na minha aplicação eu tenho uma variável SharedPreference que armazena um valor int para mim. Esse valor tem que diminuído conforme o usuário for executando umas ações, como se fosse um contador. Digamos que cada vez que o usuário tecla em um botão específico esse valor armazenado na SharedPreference diminuí 1 e tem que ser armazenado de novo com o valor atualizado.

O que acontece é que eu declaro essa variável SharedPreference no MainActivity que é o código principal entretanto, essa tela aparece uma vez só. Depois que o usuário inserir um valor que vai ser solicitado pra ele e este valor for inserido na SharedPreference a aplicação vai começar sendo executada a partir de outra tela. E é nessa outra tela que o valor sofre sua diminuição conforme o botão for clicado. E aí que eu travei. Não sei se uso a Intent pra poder passar o parametro mas, como vou conseguir armazenar o valor atualizado sendo que esta activity não vai ser mais aberta.

Tem um jeito de usar essa variável nas duas activity? Ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Você consegue aceder em qualquer *Activity* às *SharedPreference*, não entendo, por isso, a sua pergunta.

Comment: Veja: `cod_final.edit().putInt("codfinal", mostrarTexto).apply();` A variavel cod_final é a que está declarada na primeira activity. Quero que ela receba outro valor agora, mas pela segunda activity e ainda assim ser o mesmo valor para ambas. Quando insiro esta linha na segunda activity a variavel (cod_final) fica como errada e fala "cod_final cannot be resolved".

Comment: @kaamis, você está, digamos, um tanto quando "perdido", leia [isso](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), e talvez entenda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na *MainActivity* para gravar o valor nas *SharedPreference* deve estar a fazer qualquer coisa deste género;

```
SharedPreferences cod_final = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
cod_final.edit().putInt("codfinal", mostrarTexto).apply();
```

Na outra *Activity* terá de ler o valor gravado usá-lo e gravá-lo novamente:

```
SharedPreferences cod_final = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
//Ler o valor guardado de mostrartexto
int mostrarTexto = cod_final.getInt("codfinal", 0);
// use agora mostrarTexto como quizer, por ex. somar mais 1
mostrarTexto = mostraTexto + 1;
//grave novamente o novo valor de mostarTexto
cod_final.edit().putInt("codfinal", mostrarTexto).apply();
```

De volta à *MainActivity* use esse mesmo código para ler o valor alterado.

Simplificando:
Para gravar use:

```
SharedPreferences cod_final = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
cod_final.edit().putInt("codfinal", mostrarTexto).apply();
```

Para ler use:

```
SharedPreferences cod_final = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
int mostrarTexto = cod_final.getInt("codfinal", 0);
```

Comment: eu tentei adaptar seu código e estava dando certo mas o pc que eu estava quebrou e tive que formatá-lo perdendo as atualizões pois meu último backup não constava esse código. Na outra Activity o código está `cod_final = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
   int mostrarTexto2 = cod_final.getInt("codfinal",-1); ` para poder ler. Mas no Log.i que eu faço ele retorna o "-1" que é o default.

Comment: Eu declarei a variável SharedPreference como global antes do OnCreate.

Comment: Se está a retornar o *default* é porque ainda nada foi gravado. Ou seja ainda não foi feito nenhum `cod_final.edit().putInt("codfinal", mostrarTexto).apply();`

Comment: Já tinha sido feito no Main Activity. Enfim, acabei de descobrir o problema: a linha `cod_final = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` Creio eu que ela meio que resetava a variavel _shared_ .

Comment: Entretanto, muito obrigada @ramaral !