# Como salvar dados do app no smartphone?

Tags: java, android

Para não depender de conexão com a internet, é possível salvar no celular os **dados referentes ao app**? 
Por exemplo, ao abrir pela primeira vez selecionar o idioma e nas próximas utilizações do app não ser necessário perguntar o idioma, sim buscar direto do dado que foi salvo.

Comment: Que tipo de dados quer guardar?

Comment: @ramaral seriam dados pequenos, editei a pergunta

Comment: Se não tiver dificuldades com o inglês comece com este [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm). Se tiver alguma dúvida mais concreta faça uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Veja se esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55183/2541) ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No desenvolvimento Android existem várias formas de persistir os dados de um aplicativo. Uma delas é o SharedPreferences, que você pode utilizar quando se tem uma pequena coleção de chaves-valores que você gostaria de salvar (conforme a própria documentação do android diz).

Segue as principais maneiras de se utilizar o SharedPreferences:

**Criando o SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MinhasPreferencias", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Armazenandoos dados como chave-valor**

```
editor.putBoolean("key_name1", true);           // salvando um boolean - true/false
editor.putInt("key_name2", "int value");        // salvando um integer
editor.putFloat("key_name3", "float value");    // salvando um float
editor.putLong("key_name4", "long value");      // salvando um long
editor.putString("key_name5", "string value");  // salvando uma string

// salva as mudanças no SharedPreferences
editor.apply();
```

**Retornando valores do SharedPreferences**

```
// Se o valor da chave não existir, então retornará o segundo parametro
// Você pode armazenar esse retorno em uma variável 
//    Ex: String nome = pref.getString("nome", null);

pref.getBoolean("key_name1", true);         // retornando boolean
pref.getInt("key_name2", 0);             // retornando Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name3", null);           // retornando Float
pref.getLong("key_name4", null);            // retornando Long
pref.getString("key_name5", null);          // retornando String
```

**Deletando valores únicos SharedPreferences**

```
editor.remove("key_name3"); // vai deletar a chave key_name3
editor.remove("key_name4"); // vai deletar a chave key_name4

// salva as mudanças no SharedPreferences
editor.apply();
```

**Deletando todas as informações do SharedPreferences**

```
 editor.clear();
 editor.apply();
```

Um detalhe: Você pode salvar as alterações utilizando o método *apply()* e *commit()*, diferenciando que o *apply()* é assincrono.

---

Segue alguns links que possam ser úteis:

[Developer.Android - SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

[Utilizando o SharedPreferences](http://tiagomoreira.org/2013/04/utilizando-shared-preferences-no-android/)

[Resposta baseada nessa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

[Criando arquivos de configurações](http://androidzin.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/implementando-uma-tela-de-configuracao.html)

Comment: Evite utilizar o editor.commit(), pois ele salva imediatamente. Já o editor.apple() irá gerenciar o salvamento em background, não travando o processamento do app.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode armazenar em um arquivo xml, como é um [padrão para o android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html), como as activitys, manifest etc.

Comment: Poderia melhorar um pouco a sua resposta, para não ser baseada puramente em um link? Adicionar os tipos de salvamento que existe e como cada um se comporta?

Comment: A minha preocupação é onde salvar e se o usuário vai conseguir apagar esse arquivo, digo se limpar "cache"/"dados dos apps" ele será removido? Vai ter acesso ao arquivo via usb?

Comment: Sim claro, postei rapidamente porque faço isso para armazenar score de jogos.

Comment: Desculpe postar mais um link kkkkk Felipe Avelar, mais tem uma solução, uma pergunta do stack : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962344/how-to-save-data-in-an-android-app